# How to make UNION query in Access to combine data from multiple tables and ALSO exlude matched data with table named 'SignedOffClientList'?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

[image: Union Query Image of SQL code]

So the UNION query is supposed to pool all data from the tables linked to Excel Spreadsheets and then use this as a source for a second query -- which worked. But I also need to have data that is matched in another table (called 'SignedOffClientList') to be excluded from the results of the queries?

I don't know how this is done and my attempts are producing 'Syntax Error in FROM clause'... Can anyone provide advice? (Image is available in link)

TEXT of code:

```
SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [AssetFinance]

UNION


SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [Corporates]


UNION


SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [CreditConsult]

UNION


SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [FinancialMarkets]

UNION


SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [FixedIncome]

UNION


SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [ProjectFinance]

UNION


SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [RealEstate]

UNION


SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [Securitisation]

UNION SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [Treasury]

EXCEPT
SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
FROM [SignedOffClientList]


ORDER BY [F9];
```

Comment: Can you please include your code as text rather than picture? I'd also try bracketing the queries, as in SELECT * FROM T1 UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM T2 UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM T3)), that often confuses Access on joins.

Comment: Please post your query as text, not as a screenshot. Also, what's `MINUS` supposed to do? Do you want to exclude only if all columns match, or only match on a specific column?

Comment: I've edited my post to contain the current code. I don't know what I'm doing but I wanted to remove any data from all of the linked tables that is matched with any data found in the table named 'SignedOffClientList' in the results

Comment: As said, I need to know on which columns you want to match if I'm going to rite a query for you. Your query includes 15 columns, it's not usual to match on that many.

Comment: If any data from columns F1 and F2 of 'SignedOffClientList' match any data in columns F1 and F2 of any other table then those matched results should be excluded? (is that possible?)

Comment: Certainly possible, I've shared an answer.

Comment: `MINUS` is Oracle (PLSQL) specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `UNION` in a subquery, and then use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to exclude values that exist in that second table:

```
SELECT * FROM
(

    SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [AssetFinance]

    UNION


    SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [Corporates]


    UNION


    SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [CreditConsult]

    UNION


    SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [FinancialMarkets]

    UNION


    SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [FixedIncome]

    UNION


    SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [ProjectFinance]

    UNION


    SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [RealEstate]

    UNION


    SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [Securitisation]

    UNION SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11], [F12], [F13], [F14], [F15]
    FROM [Treasury]

) UnionResult
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SignedOffClientList s WHERE s.F1 = UnionResult.F1 AND s.F2 = UnionResult.F2)
```

Note that this tests for exact equality. When working with linked Excel tables, you need to take formatting characters into account if there are any.

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you very much. Also what do you mean by 'formatting characters' in Excel and how would I ensure that there are none that affect the results?

Comment: If you left-align text in Excel, Excel inserts a hidden character in the cell to indicate the result should be left-aligned. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46097678/7296893) for an example of a function that strips those. You can use the function when comparing: `RemoveNonAscii(s.F1) = RemoveNonAscii(UnionResult.F1)`. Or just make sure that the worksheet doesn't contain any formatted cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just build another query which uses the **Union Query** as datasource. In the designer join the fields with the table `SignedOffClientList` and then put your filter into this new query.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do this; could you provide further Explanation on what the 'filter' would be in order to exclude the 'SignedOffClientList'?

Comment: Just go into the query designer, then add your union query. Also add your table `SignedOffClientList`. Now join the table and the query on the field which is on both of the table/query the same (foreign key). Now drag and drop the column where the data criteria is which you want to exclude to the bottom and add your desired filter. Afterwards hit show, and you should have your desired result.